# Adding a list of words to a txt file Java

Tags: java, text, overwrite

Im trying to add a list of words taken off the end user Via a JOptionPane input menu and store them in a text file without overwriting whats already there. eg of the txt file

bell
cool
hello
now
java
compile

The problem I have is that it keeps overwriting what I have 
Any help??

```
  import javax.swing.JDialog;
  import java.util.Arrays;
  import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class write
{
public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException
{
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(aFileWriter);
 String word = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter a word");
  out.print(word);



  out.close();
  aFileWriter.close();
 }
 }
```

ok so now its appending the file but not moving to a new line for a new word??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the file:

`PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("outfilename", true)));`

Append the string to the file:

`out.println("the text");`

Close file:

`out.close();`

Better [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1625263/660408).

Answer (score 2):

Use [another constructor for FileWriter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29) that provides the 'append' argument:

```
FileWriter aFileWriter = new FileWriter("mydata.txt", true );
```

Comment: Thank you very much but how would I make the program skip to a new line for every word?

Comment: You could use `out.println(word)`

Comment: An easy way is to use out.println(word) rather than out.print(word). Welcome to StackOverflow, by the way. If you like this answer best, you can click the checkmark to its left.